How to evaluate the time complexity of this prime generating algorithm?
I’m working on a sieve algorithm to generate primes, and I’m having a hard time evaluating its time complexity.
The idea:
Fact 1: Any positive integer $>1$, except $2,3$ and their multiples, are of the form $6k\pm1$.
Fact 2: Integers of the form $6k\pm1$ which are composite are of the form $\left(6x\pm1\right)\left(6y\pm1\right)$, with $x,y>0$, and with at least $1$ such representation where $\left(6x\pm1\right)$ is prime.
Let $n$ be a composite of the form $6k\pm1$:
$$n=\left(6x\pm1\right)\left(6y\pm1\right)$$
$$n=6^{2}xy\pm6x\pm6y\pm1$$
$$n=6\left(6xy\pm x\pm y\right)\pm1$$
Here we got back to the form $6k\pm1$, where:
$$k=6xy\pm x\pm y=f\left(x,y\right)$$
The algorithm:
Start with $2$ sets, let say $S^{+}$and $S^{-}$, each containing integers from $1$ to $n$
For each pair $x,y$ such that $f\left(x,y\right)\leq n$, compute $k=f\left(x,y\right)$ and remove $k$ from the appropriate set:
$$k=f\left(x,y\right)=\begin{cases}
6xy+x+y & \rightarrow\text{remove }k\text{ from }S^{+}\\
6xy-x-y & \rightarrow\text{remove }k\text{ from }S^{+}\\
6xy+x-y & \rightarrow\text{remove }k\text{ from }S^{-}\\
6xy-x+y & \rightarrow\text{remove }k\text{ from }S^{-}
\end{cases}$$
At the end, the set $S^{+}$contains all $k\leq n$ such that $6k+1$ is prime, and the set $S^{-}$contains all $k\leq n$ such that $6k-1$ is prime.
Combined together, we get all primes up to $6n+1$, except $2$ and $3$.
At first glance it doesn't look like a sieve, because to go through each $x,y$ pairs, we need a loop within a loop, but the number of iterations is actually very small. First, because of fact $\left(2\right)$, we can skip the inner loop when $x$ has been removed from the list. Secondly, since we are evaluating the $4$ possible forms of $f\left(x,y\right)$: $\left(++,--,+-,-+\right)$, we can take only pairs where $x<=y$.
Complexity:
To generate all primes up to $N=6n+1$, the algorithm looks like this:
for($x=1\rightarrow \frac{n+1}{5}$){
    skip if $x$ has been removed from the set
     for($y=x\rightarrow\frac{k+x}{6x-1}$){
     }
}
From there I'm a little lost… How can I express the time complexity in terms of $O(N)$?
Here are some results obtained by running the algorithm to count the actual number of operations (number of iterations of the inner loop):



$N$
$n$
Operations




61
10
4


601
100
64


6001
1000
870


60001
10000
10964


600001
100000
128524


6000001
1000000
1450862


60000001
10000000
15941348


600000001
100000000
172066878



Despite the fact that the growth in the number of operations seems to indicate that from a certain point it will exceed $N$, this algorithm still seems to make it possible to generate prime numbers up to $N$ with much less than $N$ operations for very large range, at least much larger than what we could possibly store nowadays!
